# This piece of code returns an integer but it is actually not, how do I increase the precision enough to show a decimal?

Tags: python, math, precision

This is a small piece of a larger code.

```
c = (pow(1, 6) + pow(272, 6))**(1/6)

print(c)
```

It prints the output 272, but it's actually the 6th root of(272^6 + 1), the decimal point is negligible and hence it is just considered an integer.

How can I increase the precision enough to show the actual answer?

Thank You.

Comment: Why would you want `272.00000000000011194487853427598915003413248022443993784771831008` instead of `272`? the difference is less than 10^-12. You don't need that much accuracy.

Comment: And what *exactly* would you consider to be the "actual answer"?

Comment: use the [decimal](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html) module to obtain arbitrary precision

Comment: @tripleee the one with all the decimal points as mentioned in AAAlex123 's answer.

Comment: @AAAlex123 this is part of a bigger program verifying fermat's last theorem for a small test case, you can find the code here : https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/250950/ive-been-trying-to-verify-fermats-last-theorem-for-a-small-test-case-using-pyt     without this amount of precision the check if integer function doesn't work.

Comment: @AAAlex123 can you also tell me how you got that number.

Comment: Because python's integers have arbitrary precision you can do the opposite. View my answer below (wip)

Comment: @ChezhiiyanSabapathy I used WolframAlpha

Comment: Edit: nope my idea doesn't work. I thought of comparing very large numbers instead of numbers with a very long decimal expansion but it still requires long decimal expansion so we have the same problem. Have a look at @ReblochonMasque's answer. haven't tried it myself but it looks like what you need.

Comment: Edit 2: I *think* I have a solution, please do check it for yourself, I might have missed a detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [decimal](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html) module from the python standard library to obtain arbitrary precision:

```
from decimal import Decimal, getcontext


getcontext().prec = 128   # get 128 decimals

c = (pow(1, 6) + pow(272, 6)) ** (1 / 6)
print(c)

d = (Decimal(1) + Decimal(pow(272, 6))) ** Decimal((1 / 6))
print(d)
```

#### output:

```
272.0
272.00000000000002730268738756987678453728427749629247405984602995282036227860028297571745987954219978888119652759507812823846641
```

Answer (score 3):

Apart from other issues, verifying FLT by taking the nth root of a^n+b^n and checking that it isn't an integer is fundamentally misguided since the process of taking nth roots brings floating point error into play. It is possible that the numerical evidence that you adduce is by itself consistent with `c` mathematically being an integer.

For example, if root calculation could be taken at face value then

```
def f(c,n):
    return c == pow(c,n) ** (1/n)
```

should evaluate to `True` for all numbers `c`, but it doesn't. In particular `f(272,6)` evaluates to `False`. The fact that in your test case the `c` in question differs slightly from an integer doesn't show that mathematically it isn't an integer. See [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/4996248) for more details.

If you go this route, I would suggest *rounding* `c` (computed as you are currently doing) to the nearest integer and then checking if `pow(c,n) == pow(a,n) + pow(b,n)`. This way round-off error will no longer be an issue, though the limited ability of floats to represent numbers will eventually do you in. For even larger values of `a,b,n` you might need to write a custom integer root function (using e.g. binary search). In this case the integer nth root of an integer `x` is defined to be the largest integer `y` which satisfies `pow(y,n) <= x`.

Answer (score 1):

### Disclaimer: not sure if it works

Based on OP's question, [this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/250950/ive-been-trying-to-verify-fermats-last-theorem-for-a-small-test-case-using-pyt) question and its code, the comments on this post:

The idea is to compare very large numbers instead of numbers with very long decimal expansion, because pythons integers are unbounded.

First compute `c = a**g + b**g` then `s = int(c ** (1/g))`.

Now, if `(a, b, s)` is a valid triplet of numbers, then either `s**g` or `(s+1)**g` would be equal to `c` because:

- python's `int` function rounds down and
- triplets are comprised of integer numbers.

This way, we avoid directly comparing numbers with long decimal expansion by comparing very large numbers, which python can do.

Here's the code, similar to the referenced website:

```py
def proof(n, g):
    for a in range(1,n):
        for b in range(a, n):
            c = (pow(a, g) + pow(b, g))
            s = int(c ** (1/g))
            if (s**g == c):
                print(f"{a},{b},{s}")
            elif (s+1**g == c):
                print(f"{a},{b},{s+1}")

proof(1000, 6)
```

There is a trivial error (1, 1, 2) because of `s+1**g`, but other than that the code *should* work properly.

Please do check it yourself, I'm not very familiar with fermat's last theorem, something might have slipped by when coming up with a solution.

Comment: You are assuming that if c ** (1/g) is an integer then `int(c ** (1/g))` is at most 1 less than the exact answer, but this will not be true for large values of c (i.e. beyond 2 ** 53).

Answer (score -1):

You can declare float and then use round to get the nearest two decimal points. I just did this for a small pay calculation program. Something like:

```
'''
a = input ("Enter annual pay: ")
            h = float (a) / 2080
            x = round(h, 2)
            print ("Hourly pay is: ")
            print (x)
'''
```